# On moving Umbraco 4.8 project to server call to Model.MediaById crashes at Examine.ExamineManager.get_Instance()

Tags: umbraco

I am using Umbraco 4.8 and IIS 7. My code works fine when running from WebMatrix. Yesterday I moved it over to my local IIS server to test it before moving it to a remote server. I am unable to get a simple request for a media file to work. I cannot follow advice on other threads to use the Examine dashboard, as that is not compatible with 4.8. I have emptied out my media folder (in the back office and then in the folder itself) and used the desktop media uploader to put the images all back. No difference. My simple Razor file:

```
<img  src="@Model.MediaById(Model.friendlyPicture).umbracoFile" alt="picture" />
```

causes the following crash:
Error Loading Razor Script (file: Tg Profile Image) The type initializer for 'Examine.ExamineManager' threw an exception.    at Examine.ExamineManager.get_Instance()

```
 at umbraco.MacroEngines.ExamineBackedMedia.GetUmbracoMedia(Int32 id)
 at umbraco.MacroEngines.Library.RazorLibraryCore.MediaById(Int32 Id)
 at umbraco.MacroEngines.Library.RazorLibraryCore.MediaById(String Id)
 at umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode.MediaById(String Id)
 at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0,    T1 arg1)
 at ASP._Page_macroScripts_tgProfileImage_cshtml.Execute() in    c:\Websites\UmbracoSites\Todd Growns\ToddUmbracoSite\macroScripts\tgProfileImage.cshtml:line 2
 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
 at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.ExecuteRazor(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
 at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.Execute(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
```

In previous projects, I just used the Upload function to add images to pages. It seemed much better to use the MediaPicker this time, to avoid uploading images twice. I have tried to get the image to load in various ways (including inline razor macro plus the ImageGen.ashx I would like to use) but it always falls down in the same place. I do not have an Examine index in my app_data folder, so I do not see how it can be to do with a corrupt index.

There are similar bug reports in various places but none with any kind of answer I can use.

Answer (score 0):

I could look like Examine is having problems reading the ExamineIndex.config or ExamineSettings.config files.

When trying to get the media, it will first try to get it from Examine, before going to the database. In this case, it seems like it is not able to find an index, which might be because of a permissions issue, or a faulty config. Since it is working in webmatrix, I would assume that the configs are fine.

Have you tried giving the account of your app pool full permissions on your folder?

Answer (score 0):

In the past when moving sites i have after move rebuilt the indexes. In this instance its the internalindex that stores media as well as document data.

Regards

Ismail